# Query works in Enterprise postgres version but not in Community Edition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried with below query in Enterprise postgres which is working perfectly fine there but failling in open source(Community) version of postgres.

```
select (trunc(now())::date - trunc(now())::date) > '728 days' limit 1
```

I also did some modification in the query to make it compatible like

```
select (date(now())::date - date(now())::date) > '728 days' limit 1
```

but i got the error

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "728 days"

what needs to be changed here?

Comment: `(trunc(now())::date - trunc(now())::date)` will alwas return `0` - that expression makes no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "stock" Postgres you need to use `date_trunc()` because `trunc()` only works on numbers. But given your expression using `date_trunc()` is essentially useless, because the cast `::date` will achieve the same thing.

If you subtract two `DATE` values the result is an integer, not an interval, so you probably want:

```
select some_timestamp::date - current_date > 728
```

<sup>(assuming your `now()` expressions are simply placeholders for something different, because as shown, that expression doesn't make sense as the result will always be `0`)</sup>

Or if you do want to work with timestamps (and an interval) you can use:

```
select date_trunc('day', some_timestamp) - now() > interval '728 day'
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working perfectly with my scenario, (Yes, now()  just used as placeholder)